# What is the purpose of Alert inside a SQL agent job?

Tags: sql-server, sql-agent-job, sql-job

I am creating a new SQL agent job. I have already configured the job step and notifications so that the operator received an email upon failure.

I also see an option called 'Alerts' - I understand that this is a separate feature in SQL Agent. I would like to know - what is the purpose of Alert inside a SQL agent job?

Comment: Have you try check that out in the documentation ?

Comment: Yes indeed. It says `SQL Server Agent reads the application log and compares events written there to alerts that you have defined. When SQL Server Agent finds a match, it fires an alert, which is an automated response to an event. `. I understand what an alert is. But in this question I am asking- what is purpose of alert inside of an sql agent job.